# JasperReports: Exception handling in iReport

Tags: exception, jasper-reports, ireport

Is there a way to do exception handling in *JasperReports*?

Specifically, I'm interested in handling exception when a *subreport* is not found in certain URL, so that I can default the *subreport* location to another one.

I'm using the *iReport* designer, so I would like to know if there's a way to do exception handling here.

Comment: You'll need to provide more info. Are you using the iReport Designer, Jasper Library, or JasperReports Server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any generic exception handling capability built-in to iReport. But for your particular issue, perhaps you can use the "printWhenExpression" with something like:

> new Boolean(new File($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"MySubReport.jasper").exists())

for the value. Of course if you are loading the subreport remotely, it could be more complex and probably require a helper class.

Comment: well... in fact yes, I'm loading the subreport remotely, and in my particular case, I can't use any helper classes. I just have iReport and SQL datasources, and nothing else I can use

Comment: In that case, I don't think you have any options. The fact that you are using iReport though, says that you can add a Java library (helper class) or custom scriptlet if needed. Coding such a class or scriplet should not be not difficult if you know Java. You might even be able to use the HttpFileObject from Apache Commons VFS project without any coding.  But you would have to put the jar file on the iReport classpath, etc.

Comment: the thing is I don't have access to the server where the report executes. I only can upload the jasper file, but can't upload any classes to the server...

Comment: ah. Well, per my original comment (and your subsequent edit on the question), you indicated  were using iReport to execute.  It would be clearer if you stated that you are using JasperReports Server to execute the reports.  (You are using iReport to design them.)  There might be other options when using the server, but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: mmmm don't get it, even if I use JR server, I can't access it to manage any exception via no user classes. That's why I'm looking for a method to catch the 'cant locate subreport' exception (where the subreport lives in a remote url) or at least to test for its existence, FROM iReport, so I can give a default subreport in those cases. Again, that's why I specified iReport...

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of semantics then. But regardless, I don't think JasperReports library provides for generic exception handling in jxrml.

Comment: how about testing for subreport existence? If not through try/catch, at least some boolean? :D